# How to do Connection Pooling in Dgraph Java client?

Tags: java, dgraph

I am a newbie to Dgraph and I want to build an application (in Java) using Dgraph's Java Client.

The `DgraphJavaSample` talks about creating a `DgraphClient`, like this:

```
 ManagedChannel channel =
        ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9000).usePlaintext(true).build();
    DgraphBlockingStub blockingStub = DgraphGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    DgraphClient dgraphClient = new DgraphClient(Collections.singletonList(blockingStub));
```

But it doesn't tell anything about connection pooling. So, my question is - Is connection pooling required in Dgraph? If yes, then how we can create a pool of connections in Dgraph? If no, then why Dgraph doesn't need a pool of connections?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did u get anything here ?